# pass a value to 'this' in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

This there a way to pass a arbitrary value to "this" in the foo function below;

```
function foo(a){
var getThis = this;
var getA = a;

console.log("getThis:"+getThis);
console.log("\n"+a);
}

foo(5);
```

Expected output:

```
getThis: some value that I can pass
5
```

Answere to the question:

```
foo.call('some value that I can pass', 5);
```

thanks

Comment: `foo.call(42, 5)`. But, just because you can does not mean you should.

Comment: So you got your answer. Question is, why would you want that? That's what *arguments* are for

Comment: @Amit Well now you're getting pretty conceptual. Why does `this` exist at all?

Comment: @Amit it's a perfectly valid thing to do, though. After all, `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is idiomatic JavaScript and it leverages changing the the context of the `slice` method. It's also why `.bind` exists and that was added due to popular demand. People _want_ to change `this` around.

Comment: @Amit I was writting a unit test of  a function which only tests the function correctly if "this" has some predefined values

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add the answer to it. Answers should be in answers.

Answer (score 2):

Call the function using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) instead of calling it directly.

```
foo.call("this is a string", 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about `this` here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You can call the function with different `this` in the following way:

```
foo.call("hello", 5);

foo.apply("hello", [5]);
```